# Unable to compare a string in if else statement in unix

Tags: shell

```
cat sample.sh
a=$1

if [ "$a" = "Dhinakaran Ramu" ];then

        echo "Present"
else

        echo "Not Present"
fi
```

---

```
 sample.sh Dhinakaran Ramu
```

> Answer is "Not Present"

Answer (score 1):

It worked executing

```
sample.sh "Dhinakaran Ramu"
```

Note: if we execute

```
sample.sh Dhinakaran Ramu
```

then the script receives not one argument, but two. In the script you use $1, because you expect one argument.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you run the script, send the text in quotation marks:

```
$ ./sample.sh "Dhinakaran Ramu"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script $1 is Dhinakaran and $2 is  Ramu.
Try

```
sample.sh "Dhinakaran Ramu"
```